# mv: cannot stat ‘<filename>’: Input/output error

Tags: macos, debian, exfat, fuse

I have an exFAT drive formatted on macOS with many files copied over to the drive.  I can read files on the drive fine using macOS, but I cannot read operate on the directories from Debian.  I can operate on new files fine on Debian--just not on the existing files and directories.

I have exFAT support via `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` and I'm mounting the drive with `sudo mount -o umask=000 /dev/sdb2 /mnt`.

Other questions around the internet allege that this is a disk issue; however, there is no issue with the disk on macOS.  Are there any file system incompatibilities between macOS exFAT and FUSE?